# Results of OpenMP target directives on PGI

Tags: c++, openmp, pgi

I'm using PGI to compile the following program which uses OpenMP's target directives to offload work to a GPU:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(){
  const int SIZE = 400000;

  double *m;
  m = new double[SIZE];

  #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
  for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    m[i] = std::sin((double)i);

  for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    std::cout<<m[i]<<"\n";
}
```

My compilation string is as follows:

```
pgc++ -omp -ta=tesla,pinned,cc60 -Minfo=accel  -fast test2.cpp
```

Compilation succeeds, but it lacks the series of outputs that I get with OpenACC that tell me what the compiler actually did with the directive, like so:

```
main:
  8, Accelerator kernel generated
     Generating Tesla code
     11, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
  8, Generating implicit copyout(m[:400000])
```

How can I get similar information for OpenMP? `-Minfo` by itself didn't seem to yield anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"-Minfo" (which is the same as "-Minfo=all"), or "-Minfo=mp" will give you compiler feedback messages for OpenMP compilation.

Though, PGI only supports OpenMP 4.5 directives with our LLVM back-end compilers.  These are available by default on IBM Power based systems or as a part of our LLVM beta compilers on x86.  The x86 beta compilers can be found at http://www.pgroup.com/support/download_llvm.php but do require a Professional Edition license.

Also, our current OpenMP 4.5 only targets multicore CPU.  We're working on GPU target offload as well but this support wont be available for awhile.

Comment: Thanks! I'd been looking to work with OpenMP 4.5 to get a little more fine-grained control on my GPU. It doesn't seem well-supported on any compiler yet :-/