# OpenMP 4.5 runtime functions not supported in PGI

Tags: c++, openmp, pgi, offloading

When I try and compile the following code

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <accel.h>

int main (void) {
  int sum = 0;

  #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+:sum) defaultmap(tofrom:scalar)
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 2000000000; i++) {
    sum += i%11;
  }

  printf("sum = %d\n",sum);

  printf("devices %d\n", omp_get_num_devices());
  printf("default device %d\n", omp_get_default_device());
  printf("device id %d\n", omp_get_initial_device());
  return 0;
}
```

with

```
pgc++ -mp foo.cpp
```

I get the error

```
error: identifier "omp_get_num_devices" is undefined
```

The remaining OpenMP runtime functions are also undefined.  The code compiles fine with gcc7. Are these functions supported by the PGI 17.10 community edition compiler?  According to their website the PGI 17.10 community edition compiler supports OpenMP 4.5.  What am I doing wrong?

I tried this with Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PGI added support for the tasking, binding, SIMD, synchronization, reduction, atomic and other CPU features for Linux/OpenPOWER CPUs in 17.7. These features are supported in the 18.1 release of the PGI LLVM compilers for Linux x86-64. **PGI is planning to start working on the OpenMP 4.x `target` features in 2018**.

More details: https://www.pgroup.com/resources/accel.htm#openmp

Comment: It turns out that even the OpenMP features that are supported are only support by the LLVM backend enabled with `-Mllvm -mp`. But the LLVM backend is not supported by the community edition anyway for x86 (but are by with IBM Power). I will use PGI for OpenACC and not for OpenMP.

Comment: My question is to some degree a duplicate of this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/47980530/2542702